# Cross platform system call from R running generated rscript

Tags: r, system

I'm trying to write a function that can run a separate rscript (to launch a shiny plot function while the original function is working), but cross platform issues are a major headache. I would like to find a way to avoid the 'if windows ==TRUE' statement in the following code. There seem to be issues with differences in the needed escape characters on different systems - so far I have tested on ubuntu and windows.

```
windows=FALSE


tmpdir=tempdir()
tmpdir=gsub('\\','/',tmpdir,fixed=TRUE)
  # tmpdir=gsub('\\','\\/',tmpdir,fixed=TRUE)

wd<-  paste0("setwd('",tmpdir,"')")
writeLines(text=paste0(wd,'
  testout<-5
  save(testout,file=paste0("testout.rda"))
'),con=paste0(tmpdir,"/testscript.R"))

if(windows) system(paste0("Rscript --slave --no-restore -e source(\'",tmpdir,"/testscript.R\')"),wait=FALSE) else
  system(paste0("Rscript --slave --no-restore -e source\\(\\\'",tmpdir,"\\/testscript.R\\\'\\)"),wait=FALSE)
```

Comment: One strength of Shiny is that it embeds a web server. So you'd be better off serving your application as a web app, hosted on your own server, thus maintaining only one copy of your code on one system

Comment: The shiny portion is just a very small portion of the software package, for plotting while optimization / sampling is occurring.

Comment: Can you define a function to build the path and "hide" the OS-checks in there?

Comment: Yes, I could just do a bunch of os checks , and then testing across every os  - I'm hoping / asking for some sort of generic solution that avoids os specific checks and just works!